# Баги с отрисовкой формы в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Почему происходят такие баги с отрисовкой и как от них избавится?

### При наведение на кнопку происходит такое:

[image: Кнопка]

### Или при изменении размеров формы происходят какие-то разрывы. Бывает вся форма становится черной пока не изменишь размер вновь

[image: Разрывы]

### Такие же баги с отрисовкой в Visual Studio. Бывает форма вся меняет цвет, или на всю форму растягивается TextBox, после скрола всё проходит моментально

[image: VS]

Comment: Гаданием по скриншотам мы здесь не занимаемся. WPF использует DirectX для отрисовки, обновите дрова и DX. Задайте минимальные размеры окон, чтобы нельзя было их сплющивать в кашу. Убедитесь в том, не висит ли окно, какая нагрузка на процессор идет в этот момент.

Comment: @aepot Такие же баги с отрисовкой есть в самой Visual Studio (В Windows Forms и WINUI 3 таких багов с отрисовкой нету)

Comment: Писал под все 3 платформы, ничего подобного никогда не было.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После 6 часов поиска проблемы оказалось что программа Sonic Studio (программа для воспроизведения звука со звуковой карты) каким-то образом влияла на отрисовку. После полного завершения (со всеми процессами) баги с отрисовкой пропали, и все лаги моментально прошли.

> Как пишут на зарубежных форумах, всё дело в **Nahimic** (в моём это процесс "**nhAsusStrixSvc64**")